Locked out of Wordpress.com
I'm hosting all my Wordpress sites myself, but a few plugins require an account on Wordpress.com. However, when I try to login there, it's saying

"Limit reached. You can try again in 30 minutes. Trying again before
that will only increase the time you have to wait before the ban is
lifted. If you think this is in error, contact support."

However, the Wordpress.com support site basically links to only itself, there doesn't seem to be a contact form. Other support options require logging in, which I can't. Trying to reset the password doesn't help, as this doesn't change the fact that the user ID / email address is locked. I'm actually pretty sure that my none of my 'connection' accounts are interesting enough to be 'hacked' or hunted by bots, so are there other potential causes for my problem? I've also tried with different browsers and removed all cookies, nothing helps.

If you log in to your Wordpress.com account, there's a "Get Help" button that'll open an AI assistant chat, which seems like a place to start.

Thanks, but on the "Log in to WordPress.com" page I see there is no "Get Help" button... Top left: Wordpress logo, top right: "Create an account", a "lost password?" link and apart from that just 3rd party login options (Google etc.).

The Get Help button appears after you've logged in.


Disconnect all connecting plugins, so they no longer attempt to utilise that specific wordpress.com account.

Wait for the wordpress.com time out to expire.

Try to manually login to wordpress.com, to confirm all if well again.

If you still can not get in, give the wordpress.com Account Recorvery process a go and then repreat step 3.


Note that step 1 should ensure that the account lock is no longer being continually re-enforced by external services (you plugins trying to do their thing).

Reconnect all the connecting plugins you were originally using.

